# Keyboard Shortcut - Highlight to bottom of range based on data one column over

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I work with similar data pulls frequently and am trying to be more efficient in how I transform them.

Typically, I will autofill a field down to the end of the range one column over by using the little black cross displayed when mousing over the active cell:

[image]

In this example, I need to fill rows 3 on down by continuing the series in column A. If I use keyboard shortcuts, I can reach the fill (and autofill) dialogue box, but I first have to scroll down to highlight to the bottom of the dates' data one column to the right.  This can be very tedious in a big data set, because <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> takes me to the bottom of the sheet, not the intended range.

The black cross icon accessed through the mouse understands this logic, but I can't figure out how to reproduce it with shortcuts.

Any thoughts?
It would be super helpful!

Comment: How do you do it with the black cross icon?

Answer (score 0):

Select the first cell of the date column (near `1` - with date `2018-05-27` in it), then

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> - to select all dates,
- then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> - to expand selection to the left,
- then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> - to make the cell with `1` active, without canceling the current selection,
- then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> - to shrink selection to the left column.

Comment: I tried this and it simply added thousands of empty lines to my sheet.

Comment: The first point, Ctrl+Shift+down arrow, supposes that you have already selected the first date (`2018-05-27`) and that you have at least one other date beneath of it.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from any cell in the incomplete column (1 or 2 in your example):

- Right arrow to get into the column of dates
- Ctrl + Down arrow to go to the bottom of the column of dates
- Left arrow
- Ctrl + Shift + Up arrow to select all the blank cells in that column up to the one beneath the 2.

Then type a formula (e.g., `=A5+1`) and press Ctrl + Enter to enter in all selected cells, or use Ctrl + D to fill down from, or whatever you need.